# Replace do_shortcode() with direct function when you have shortcode within shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to avoid using `do_shortcode()` and would like to instead replace it with the functions themselves. The issue I am having is with the closing shortcode tag. How is this accomplished using the function?

Rewrite this:

```
echo do_shortcode( "
[membership level='12,41']
[get_biddata type='pending' sport='MLB Baseball']
[/membership]
    " );
```

With this:

```
echo pmpro_shortcode_membership( array( 'level' => '12,41', 'levels' => NULL, 'delay' => NULL ), $atts);
echo ajax_member_support( array( 'sport' => 'MLB Baseball', 'type' => 'pending' ), $atts );
```

What argument, if any, goes in this function:

`echo pmpro_shortcode_membership();`
 to replace this:`[/membership]` ending shortcode tag?

There are 3 Plugins:

1) Paid Memberships - shortcode tags = `[membership] [/membership]`

shortcode callback function name: `pmpro_shortcode_membership()`

2) bidsys - shortcode tag = `[get_biddata]`

shortcode callback function name: `ajax_member_support()`

3) My own custom plugin to create shortcodes for my site where the do_shortcode is being used in a file.

The issue I am having with hard coding the calls to get rid of `do_shortcode()`. It only seems to work properly when wrapped in `[membership] [/membership]` tags.

**WHAT WORKED FOR MY PARTICULAR SITUATION:**

ANSWER/CODE FROM ArtisticPhoenix:

```
echo pmpro_shortcode_membership(
   array( 'level' => '12,41', 'levels' => NULL, 'delay' => NULL ),
   ajax_member_support( array( 'sport' => 'MLB Baseball', 'type' => 'pending' ))
);
```

Comment: There is no way to know because that string only shows in the first example as something php could edit.  It could be as simple as `str_replace('[/membership]', '', $string)`  or `preg_replace('/\[[-\w]+\]/', '', $sting)`, but without knowing where that is, who can tell?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix What more information is required? I attempted to rephrase the content within my question as perhaps it is misunderstood.

Comment: first off a shortcode function is typically `function foo($attr, $content)` not `function foo($array, $attr)`  but where does this text (in the first block) come from what is it assigned to etc.  How can one remove a string from (presumably) another string if we don't know what it's assigned to.  If you are just replacing the first block with the second, you should not have an end tag to replace.

Comment: If you are taking the contents of another shortcode, and replacing the `do_shortcode` call, you will have to parse the contents for the shortcodes at which time you are better off using the built in functions for this...  In other words there is no "Context" to your question.  Your either getting it from a post or whatnot, or its manually created and that is not clear.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I posted the actual function itself from which I am echoing in my file. Currently the file I am editing uses `do_shortcode()` which I'm trying to avoid. All works ok until I get to this closing tag. I don't know what to echo

Comment: How do you know `$content` will always include exactly this set of shortcodes in your example?  Including all the various attributes.  You cannot be sure of that, which means you would have to parse nested shortcodes from a string, which is exactly what `do_shortcode` is for.  So why re-write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not re-write `do_shortcode`.

That is the answer ... in short.

HERE I am assuming that your post is something like this

```
 [myshortcode]
     [membership level='12,41']
         [get_biddata type='pending' sport='MLB Baseball']
     [/membership]
 [/myshortcod]
```

It's the only thing that makes sense to me.  Because if you have

```
[membership level='12,41']
    [get_biddata type='pending' sport='MLB Baseball']
[/membership]
```

And your shortcode is `membership` then if you call `do_shortcode` on the above, you will get infinite recursion (or at least membership would run 2x).  I am pretty sure wordpress removes the current shortcodes tags and replaces them with the return value of that shortcodes function... or this would be a major issue.  But it's unclear what shortcode is yours and what is the ones your trying to include in your shortcode.

Also if you look in the WP documentation for enclosed shortcodes [HERE](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/enclosing-shortcodes/)

There is no mention of removing the ending tag of the current shortcode. Hense my confusion as you said:

> [here is the] Function for the membership shortcode:

Which leads one to believe that `[membership]` calls that function, and then you are trying to do `do_shortcode` on the same shortcode `[membership ...]`.  Which is not really sensible to me.

**First Off**

Shortcodes are written (typically) like this:

```
 function foo($atts, $content)  // array, string
```

Not

```
 function foo($myarray, $atts) //array, array
```

So when you call:

```
 echo pmpro_shortcode_membership(
           array( 'level' => '12,41', 'levels' => NULL, 'delay' => NULL ),
            $atts
 );
```

Which I assume is where that shortcode leads, the arguments are wrong...

**Now, Let me explain (the above answer, do not remake do_shortcode).**

If you hard code this and instead of this:

```
[membership level='12,41']
   [get_biddata type='pending' sport='MLB Baseball']
[/membership]
```

You get (as $contents)

```
[membership level='13,41']  //note the 13,14 not 12,14
   [get_biddata type='pending' sport='MLB Baseball']
[/membership]
```

Because you cannot grantee this case in your code, you must account for it.  To do that you would have to parse the shortcode yourself (to get the level attribute), which is what `do_shortcode` does.

Additionally lets assume this shortcode `membership` adds some HTML like

```
  <div>
        [get_biddata type='pending' sport='MLB Baseball']
  </div>
```

And the other `get_biddata` does something like

```
   <a href="example.com" >Click</a>
```

Because the second one (above) is nested inside the other shortcode you get

```
  <div>
        <a href="example.com" >Click</a>
  </div>
```

If you run these one after the other (as you tried to)

```
   <div>

   </div>
   <a href="example.com" >Click</a>
```

And this HTML could be way more complex then a simple `<div>`.  So the ending shortcode is really the least of the problems.

Maybe this isn't your situation, but it's not worth re-inventing `do_shortcode` to save a few micro-seconds (at best, perhaps it will be worse after you parse it yourself).

Not to mention this would be a minefield trying to parse, because of the need for recursion etc...

**Finally**

If you just want to include this functionality in all the calls to your short code, then you can just hardcode the calls to those methods (and leave them out of the post entirely)

You could switch on what attributes are passed to your shortcode on if you should do the others, but that is up to you.

```
//do your code like this (in the post):
//    [myshortcode sport='foo' level='12,41']
//instead of like this
//   [myshortcode][membership level='12,41'] ... [/myshortcode]

echo pmpro_shortcode_membership(
     array( 'level' => '12,41', 'levels' => NULL, 'delay' => NULL ),
     "[get_biddata type='pending' sport='MLB Baseball']"
);
```

As shown above, you still can pass the inner shortcode as a shortcode to the first method/function.  So that it will be placed in any HTML in the correct location. This does allow you to use your own attributes in the construction of that shortcode.

For example:

```
//$atts['sport'] could come from your shortcode Attributes (as shown above).
echo pmpro_shortcode_membership(
     array( 'level' => $attr['level'], 'levels' => NULL, 'delay' => NULL ),
     "[get_biddata type='pending' sport='{$atts['sport']}']"
);
```

You could also do it this way (by passing the results of the inner one to the outer one as it's content) and avoid `do_shortcode`:

```
echo pmpro_shortcode_membership(
   array( 'level' => $attr['level'], 'levels' => NULL, 'delay' => NULL ),
   ajax_member_support( array( 'sport' => 'MLB Baseball', 'type' => 'pending' ))
);
```

Basically the `ajax_member_support` executes first, then it's contents is placed in the `$contents` of the outer shortcode.  This works in this example, but if the nesting was deeper you would have some issues...

But if you do the above (in this "section"), you SHOULD NOT allow those other shortcodes to be nested within your shortcode.  Instead you should pass their arguments as part of your own shortcode. It will make life way easier and prevent a lot of issues if you piggyback those attributes as part of your shortcode (whatever that is)...

Hope that makes sense.

**One last thing** (that just sort of bugged me)

This bit of code:

```
  if(!empty($level) || $level === "0" || $level === 0)
  //if level is not empty, or it is string '0' or just 0
```

Can be simplified, because we know that only strings can be passed from a shortcode attribute.  So instead of that stuff:

```
  if(strlen($level))
     //empty (such as null) is 0, but string '0' and 0 are strlen 1.
```

To illustrate this, we cannot pass an array in a shortcode like this

```
[membership level="[3,4]"]
```

Because it will just be a string `[3,4]`.  Which you know (because you had to parse the level from a string), but probably didn't realize. So now that we agree only strings can be passed though a shortcode we can test this:

```
echo strlen(0)."\n";
echo strlen('0')."\n";
echo strlen(false)."\n";
echo strlen(null)."\n";
```

Output

```
1 //strlen(0)
1 //strlen('0')
0 //strlen(false)
0 //strlen(null)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/96148e2129c5755eb40ce9023d5134ad59c6e5d7)

And it should be obvious that `strlen('')` is `0` as well.  And because you "properly" used `shortcode_atts` if level is not set, it will default to `NULL` (so we don't have to worry about undefined/notset).  Therefor, the two pieces of code are roughly equivalent, except one is shorter.

It may seem a bit "weird" but if we know that we only have to deal with primitives (non-array, non-object) and it's guaranteed to be set (which is the case here). Than `strlen` should be fine.

Cheers!

**UPDATE**

For more then 2 shortcodes you would just continue to nest the functions into the content of the parent one:

```
echo pmpro_shortcode_membership(
   array( 'level' => $attr['level'], 'levels' => NULL, 'delay' => NULL ),
   ajax_member_support(
          array( 'sport' => 'MLB Baseball', 'type' => 'pending' ),
          some_other_shortcode(
              ['foo'=>'bar'],
              some_other_shortcode_1(
                   ['biz'=>'baa'],
                    ......
               )
          )
   )
);
```

And so on, the inner most functions execute first and likely return some kind of string, then that string is passed to the parent functions.  Because the parent function is using this content to look for other shortcodes via `$content = do_shortcode($content)`.  When that is called in the parent function, the content which would have been an executed shortcode, was already done for it before you called it.  But do_shortcode will return the text, even if there is no shortcode there (because it's already been done). So it falls right into pace where is should have had it not been done beforehand.

Basically you are just feeding it the content it would have gotten anyway from do_shortcode so everything works (in most cases).

Comment: Great information thank you, however it still does not seem to work in my situation...yet. I provided more information in my question to help you further understand what is going on as I continue to attempt to find a solution.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what any of these shortcodes do, I was just assuming they return some kind of content such as HTML, which is typical of shortcodes.  However it's not impossible that they instead do things.   So you may have to adjust accordingly.  In any case even if you do them one after the other, I would eliminate the other shortcodes in the post (or whatever) if possible as I outline above, as it makes things way easier to deal with.  Good luck.

Comment: They really do just put out HTML from `ajax_member_support` i.e. `[get_biddata]`based on the user membership level within`[membership] [/membership]`. It just says who has access, and who doesn't, to what content. Depending on membership level would determine the content the see. I thought it would be something simple to replace `do_shortcode()` but I must be missing something somewhere. Your answer has been quite educational nonetheless.

Comment: This piece of code you provided does indeed work in my situation as long as `'level' => '12,41'` is written this way-- `echo pmpro_shortcode_membership(
   array( 'level' => '12,41', 'levels' => NULL, 'delay' => NULL ),
   ajax_member_support( array( 'sport' => 'MLB Baseball', 'type' => 'pending' ))
);` If I use: `'level' => $attr['level'],` it does not work for whatever reason.

Comment: What if you had more than one inner shortcode like:     `[membership level='1,2,3']
    [get_biddata type='current' sport='NFL Football']
    [get_biddata type='past' sport='NFL Football']
    [get_biddata type='detailed' sport='NFL Football']
    [/membership]` How would you hardcode the calls using your function: `echo pmpro_shortcode_membership(
   array( 'level' => '1,2,3, 'levels' => NULL, 'delay' => NULL ),
   ajax_member_support( array( 'sport' => 'NFL Football', 'type' => 'current' ))
);`

Comment: you would just continue to nest them in the content argument.

Comment: Ok but what if all the shortcodes were using the same function like so? `echo pmpro_shortcode_membership(
    array( 'level' => $attr['level'], 'levels' => NULL, 'delay' => NULL ),
    ajax_member_support(
          array( 'sport' => 'NFL Football', 'type' => 'current' ),
          ajax_member_support(
              array( 'sport' => 'NFL Football', 'type' => 'past' ),
              ajax_member_support(
                   array( 'sport' => 'NFL Football', 'type' => 'detailed' )
               )
          )
    )
);` It does not work. Only the first array executes.